# jQuery multiselect - hid optgroup options on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-multiselect

I'm using jQuery multiselect, that can be found here: http://loudev.com/#home

I want to hide the options of an optgroup when clicked. I have fooled around with this in the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/EvTheCOSCStudent/sbehzm5d/6/), but I can't hide an option if it has been added back to the opgroup. Also, once an option is selected is still shows if an optgroup is hidden. Is there a way to achieve hidden optgroup options?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <select id="optgroup" multiple="multiple">
        <optgroup label="OptOne">
           <option value="elem1">Elem 1</option>
           <option value="elem2">Elem 2</option>
           <option value="elem3">Elem 3</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="OptTwo">
            <option value="elem4">Elem 4</option>
            <option value="elem5">Elem 5</option>
            </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="OptThree">
            <option value="elem6">Elem 6</option>
            <option value="elem7">Elem 7</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$('#optgroup').multiSelect({
    selectableOptgroup: false,

    afterSelect: function (values, text) {
        _self = this;
        // if there are more than 6 elements selected
        if (this.$element.val().length > 4) {

            // disable all selectable elements
            var selectables = this.$container.find('.ms-elem-selectable');
            selectables.addClass(_self.options.disabledClass);

            // disable all <option>            
            var options = _self.$element.find('option');
            options.prop('disabled', true);
        }
    },
    afterDeselect: function (values, text) {
        _self = this;

        // if there are less than 6 elements selected
        if (this.$element.val() && this.$element.val().length < 4) {

            // enable all selectable elements
            var selectables = this.$container.find('.ms-elem-selectable');
            selectables.removeClass(_self.options.disabledClass);

            // enable all <option>            
            var options = _self.$element.find('option');
            options.prop('disabled', false);
        }
    }
});
$("body").on('click', '.ms-optgroup-label', function () {
    $(this).siblings().toggle();
})
```

CSS:

```
.ms-container{
  background: transparent url('../img/switch.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
  width: 76.5vh;
}

.ms-container:after{
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  clear: both;
  min-height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.ms-container .ms-selectable, .ms-container .ms-selection{
  background: #fff;
  color: #555555;
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
}
.ms-container .ms-selection{
  float: right;
}

.ms-container .ms-list{
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  -o-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  height: 30vh;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.ms-container .ms-list.ms-focus{
  border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
  outline: 0;
  outline: thin dotted \9;
}

.ms-container ul{
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.ms-container .ms-optgroup-container{
  width: 100%;
}

.ms-container .ms-optgroup-label{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
  color: #3a6f91;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.ms-container .ms-selectable li.ms-elem-selectable,
.ms-container .ms-selection li.ms-elem-selection{
  border-bottom: 1px #eee solid;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.ms-container .ms-selectable li.ms-hover,
.ms-container .ms-selection li.ms-hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #08c;
}

.ms-container .ms-selectable li.disabled,
.ms-container .ms-selection li.disabled{
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #aaa;
  cursor: text;
}
```

Comment: Check the console, you have `(index):131 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null` - it is because you "this" changed to new element, which not in initial selection.

Comment: I don't see this error. My question is how I can sync both sides of the groups when hiding options.

Comment: I would do it much simpler: create 2 identical full selects with same IDs but `hidden` class `false` for left and `true` - for right, than on any click toggle 'hidden' class for `$(this.id)` - it will show/hide similar item on both sides in any case

Comment: Interesting idea, could you write a small example?